# iOS9 - CNContactPickerViewController : SelectionOfProperty is not working, if user have multiple phone numbers

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

SelectionOfProperty is not working if user has multiple phone numbers.

I am using below code:

```
let picker = CNContactPickerViewController()
picker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

picker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0")

picker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(value: false) 

picker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(format: "key == 'phoneNumbers'")
picker.delegate = self
```

It's working perfectly fine when we using emailAddresses, but not when we changed to phoneNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple phone numbers set the predicateForEnablingContact as

```
picker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 1")
```

set the predicate format as "phoneNumbers.@count > 1"